# File.Copy in C# NOT Working

Tags: c#, file, copy

After using the File.Copy function to copy a text file from one location to another i try the exact same functionality (that i've already gotten to work) on another text file fails to write.  However, the weird part is that there is NO EXCEPTION thrown! I know the file exists by doing

```
if(File.Exist(myFile))
```

My File.Copy code:

```
File.Copy(sourceFilePathCombined, targetFilePathCombined, true);
```

This works well for one file in the same directory, but not for the other.  There is NO exception. Why won't it write the file, but the other file gets copied without issue?

Code for those who need it:

```
         var indexFileDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Accident.IndexFileDirectory"];
         var xRefToDoList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Accident.XRefToDoList"];
         var xRefToDoResult = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Accident.XRefToDoResult"];
         var toDoFilePath = Path.Combine(indexFileDirectory, xRefToDoResult);
         var indexFilePath = Path.Combine(indexFileDirectory , xRefToDoList);

          //Includes date-time stamp to suffix the file
        var xRefToDoResultsDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddhhmmss");

        //If the directory does not exist then create it
        if (!Directory.Exists(XRefPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(XRefPath);
        }
        var indexToStart = xRefToDoList.IndexOf(".");
        var test2 = xRefToDoList.Remove(indexToStart, 4);

        indexToStart = xRefToDoResult.IndexOf(".");
        var test3 = xRefToDoResult.Remove(indexToStart, 8);
         var xRefToDoListCombinedPath = Path.Combine(XRefPath, (test2 + "_lst" + "." + xRefToDoResultsDateTime));
         var xRefResultListCombinedPath = Path.Combine(XRefPath, (test3 + "_results" + "." + xRefToDoResultsDateTime));
         string extension = Path.GetExtension(toDoFilePath);

            try
        {
            File.Copy(indexFilePath, xRefToDoListCombinedPath, true);//THIS WORKS!

            File.Copy(toDoFilePath, xRefResultListCombinedPath, true);//this does NOT
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var test = ex;
        }
```

Comment: Do you have proper permission's?

Comment: What are the values of `sourceFilePathCombined` and `targetFilePathCombined`?

Comment: They are local paths in a directory that DOES exist.  If it didn't then i would have an exception, which i don't.  If the file didn't exist then i would have an exception, which i don't.

Comment: Are both File.Copy calls using the same targetFilePathCombined value? If not, check if you have proper permissions like Greg said.

Comment: By chance is this code inside a form constructor? Your exception has a good chance of getting eaten if it is.

Comment: I checked and i do have correct permissions.  The same targetFilePathCombined value is being used.  There is no form constructor.

Comment: Since there are no errors or exceptions, it seems that a file IS being copied.   You are most likely looking in the wrong place (wrong server, drive, directory, file name....)

Comment: That's what i would think, but i'm in the correct directory.  In fact, i'm actually using the EXACT same TWO directories (i.e. soureDirectory and targetDirectory).  The only difference here is the file, itself.  Weird, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try using foreach to move all files

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

foreach (var file in files)
{
    string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
    string target = Path.Combine(targetPath, name);
    File.Copy(file, target, true);
}
```

Comment: after implementing this code i still have the exact same problem: i can move the other file but not the one i want.

Comment: As it turns out there actually was NO problem.  I was even looking in the correct folder.  However, i was looking at the Modified Date and thinking it never copied since i didn't bother to check the Created Date.  Oops! My bad...

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to not confuse Date Modified with Date Created when looking for the file in a directory.  It may look like it didn't get created if it has a Date Modified value.